# Selenium says element clicked 'successfully', but, it is not actually clicked

Tags: java, selenium, click

[image]

I have a scenario where I need to click Continue button.Even I gave print message after click function.The message is printing but the button is not clicking.I have tried java script executor,explicit wait(elementtobeclickable)But still its not clicking.What is the other solution.
This is what I have tried till now

```
    By click_continue= By.xpath("//input[@id='btnWFContinue']");

    if(driver.findElement(click_continue)!=null) {      
    waitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(click_continue)));
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(click_continue);
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
    log.info("Clicked on Continue!!!");

 /*
WebElement element = driver.findElement(click_continue);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();        
driver.findElement(click_continue).click();    */
   }else {
  log.info("Continue button is not present moving to next step");
 }
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: yes updated the question

Comment: adding code as image is bad practice no one will write that code for you. please add  relevant html code of element you trying interact

Comment: how do you know that the Continue button is not being clicked?  perhaps that is where the code is broken.

Comment: because if continue button is clicked ,screen will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Open the desired page in your browser and open the browser console . Execute the below code in the same
    $("input[id='btnWFContinue']").click() or document.getElementById("btnWFContinue").click()

If the element is clickable , then the above javascript command must change the webpage. Use the same in your script as well. Other there is no click event associated with your element.

Answer (score 0):

try placing a wait statement before your if statement. Its possible that the code executes before the elemnt is loaded and the code jumps to the else part.